# holding movement and dashing by tapping shift

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

im trying to get my character to dash the direction its currently moving when i tap shift. right now i have to hold shift then tap the direction i want to dash.

ive tried switching up the order, and ive tried changing the code to use a double tap to dash. with no luck so far

```
public class Dash : MonoBehaviour
{

private Rigidbody rb;

public float dashSpeed;
private float dashTime;
public float startDashTime;
private int direction;


void Update()
{
    //dash
    if (direction == 0)
    {
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftShift) && Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.A))
        {
            direction = 1;
        }
        else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftShift) && Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.D))
        {
            direction = 2;
        }
        else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftShift) && Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.W))
        {
            direction = 3;
        }
        else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftShift) && Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.S))
        {
            direction = 4;
        }
```

I want the character to dash to the left. I want to be able to hold down the "A" key to strafe in that direction and tap "Shift" to do a short dash.

if i hold "A" i strafe in the direction but "Shift" does nothing. if i hold "Shift" then tap "A" the character does the dash i expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of:

```
if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftShift) && Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.A))
```

Try:

```
if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftShift) && Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A))
```

`Input.GetKeyDown` olnly returns `true` in the first frame the key is pushed, while `Input.GetKey` returns `true` every frame you are holding the key